# BGE 'KX Scene' object has no attribute 'world'

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

Как в версии Blender 2.69 получить world объект в игре?

По всем урокам что я нашёл используется только так:

```
import bge

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
world = scene.world
```

но у меня на версии blender 2.69 выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "MistColor.py", line 10, in <module>
AttributeError: 'KX_Scene' object has no attribute 'world'
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте задать этот вопрос на http://blender.stackexchange.com/